# UISplitView showDetailViewController: not working on a device

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview, uisplitviewdelegate

I have a home page and when a certain button is pressed, it takes you to a split view with a table on the left (master) side and a view showing details on the right (detail) side.  The app is working fine on the simulator, but when I run on my iPad mini I get an error.

When the user clicks on a table cell in the left (master) view, I call:

```
DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailViewController"];
detail.jobInfo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:detail sender:self];
```

That updates the detail view in the simulator, but crashes and gives me the following error on a device:

```
'-[UISplitViewController showDetailViewController:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the device on iOS 8?

Comment: no it has 7.1.2, does that method only work on iOS 8?

Comment: Could you suggest a way to get this same result for earlier versions of iOs?

Comment: Update the viewControllers property: viewControllers[0] is the master, [1] is the detail.  But if you have a navigation controller on the detail side, you might prefer to push onto that instead.

Comment: The entire SplitView is in a navigation controller.  I tried updating the viewControllers property and received the same error: unrecognized selector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62759/discussion-between-pbasdf-and-msu-bulldog).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To update the viewControllers property directly, do this:

```
NSArray *vcs = @[self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0],detail];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = vcs;
```

Comment: Perfect Answer! All was workin fine on simulator but on device crash! this answer fixed it!